# Length of Category Names

Tags: categories

Based on this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7587/organizing-by-super-categories-or-nested-categories), I'm hoping to create good categories now, that I won't have to change much later.

1. Can you change a category name later, without having to go back and re-categorize all articles?
2. Using the category "Information Technology" as a challenging example, would you call it: 
   a. IT 
   b. I.T. 
   c. InfoTech 
   d. InformationTechnology 
   e. Information Technology 
   (in other words, is shorter better?  any downside of long category names? any problem with a space in the category?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.: Yes (Slugs differ then, but no need for you to re-categorize each post)

2.: As you wrote: "Information Technology". As a rule of thumb, Category Names should be between 2 and 26 characters, the actual length depends on your site and your needs as there is no hard nor soft limit to category length and there is no "ideal" or "perfect" category length. This needs to be decided individual based on preference and site content, context and the the current time. See as well [your previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7587/organizing-by-super-categories-or-nested-categories).

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question, that one worry was that the categories might be menu links.

Comment: That's what the *Navigation Label* is for when you create nav menus(assuming you're using the 3.0 menus), you can shorten or change the menu items label to whatever you want(though by default it will inherit the name of the item being added, be it a category or whatever else).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can change the category name later, and all posts assigned to the "old" category will automatically have the new category name. As long as the category ID is intact.
2. I would say that you should use long and somewhat describing category titles. So, to your concrete question, I would go for Information Technology.

Comment: What is the menu/link to get to the screen to update the existing category names?

Comment: I see it now - right under "Posts"...  I was guessing it would have been in settings or somewhere else.